# Can anyone explain why sudo ls with a wildcard doesn't work?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, wildcards

```
$ sudo -iu abc ls -ltr /sites/servers/server_instance/logs/access*
ls: cannot access /sites/servers/server_instance/logs/access*: No such file or directory

$ sudo -iu abc ls -ltr /sites/servers/server_instance/logs/
total 594812
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc      45 Mar 21 12:42 old.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc      304537970 Mar 24 12:45 console.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abc abc      304537970 Mar 24 13:20 access_nginx.log
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? I am stuck on a script due to this.

Answer (score 32):

One possibility is that you don't have permissions to access one or more of the directories in that path (`/sites/servers/server_instance/logs`). The wildcard expansion is carried out by your shell, and then the expanded paths are passed to the `sudo` command.

If your user doesn't have permissions, expansion wouldn't work in the first command. It would be run as-is (`ls -ltr /sites/servers/server_instance/logs/access*`), and there isn't a file literally named `access*`). If `abc` does have the required permissions for all the directories in the path, the second command, which didn't have any wildcards, would be untouched by your shell, and it would work fine.

```
$ sudo namei -lx foo/bar/baz
f: foo/bar/baz
drwxr-xr-x muru    muru    foo
drwx------ test    test    bar
drwxr-xr-x muru    muru    baz

$ sudo ls foo/bar/b*
ls: cannot access 'foo/bar/b*': No such file or directory

$ sudo -u test ls foo/bar/
baz
```

Comment: thanks Muru , your opinion was correct , i changed the permission to 755 and now its working fine.

Comment: @Faisal: I would think that changing permissions is not the proper remedy, though it reveals that the diagnosis is correct. The proper remedy would seem to be to not do globbing while preparing the sudo command, but rather suppress it here (by quoting the path argument), passing the argument as-is to the `ls` command that can then (when the identity change from `su` has taken effect) do the globbing.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen `ls` doesn't do any globbing.

Comment: You can make globbing happen in the sudo environment by adding `sh -c` to the command line.

Comment: @Faisal if that answers your question, consider accepting it...

Comment: It worked fine for me.. Thanks for answering..

Comment: @StigHemmer Thanks a lot -- I wanted a workaround, not just an answer why it doesn't work. Just to spell out your solution, it's `sudo bash -c "ls -d /foo/bar/*"`.

Comment: `sudo sh -c "ls --color=always foo/bar/" | less -R` for a colorized list that doesn't disrupt the scrollback buffer. Thanks @Noumenon and @StigHemmer.

Answer (score 7):

You may have globbing disabled.

Look for something like `set -f` or `set -o noglob` before those lines in the script, or if in an interactive shell run `echo $-`; if there's an `f` in the output, globbing is disabled:

```bsh
$ echo $-
fhimBH
```

To fix that, remove `set -f` or `set -o noglob` from the script, or if in an interactive shell run `set +f` or `set +o noglob`:

```bsh
$ set -f
$ echo $-
fhimBH
$ ls access*
ls: cannot access access*: No such file or directory
$ set +f
$ echo $-
himBH
$ ls access*
access
```

Comment: Yeah, i as my individual user don't have access to that path. In script i am going as my user (via ssh) and running that command via production user. Is there any work around for this ?   (One point to noted is i don't have to give password for switching user)

Comment: @Faisal How about running the script as the target user (`sudo -u abc /path/to/script`)? In that case globbing shouldn't fail. In any case muru suggested the path issue in his answer, not me. You should consider accepting his answer (http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Actually i am running that on remote machine  via script so -i would be needed. Thanks to you as well for answering.